# AppCompat and ViewPagerIndicator fragments submenu not showing

Tags: android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator, android-actionbar-compat

I have a pretty simple use case which does not work with the AppCompat library on Android 8.

I have one Activity that includes two fragments that can be swipped between using a TabPagerIndicator. The first of the fragments shows an SubMenu on the ActionBar, the second does not.

When starting the activity the first fragment is shown. Clicking the SubMenu correctly shows the SubMenu items for selection. However, if swiping to fragment two and back again, clicking the SubMenu does nothing.

Instead of supplying large blocks of code here, I have created a sample project that shows the problem. It is on github: https://github.com/foens/appcompatsubmenu/

Shortcuts:

- [Activity code](https://github.com/foens/appcompatsubmenu/blob/master/src/main/java/foo/bar/test/TestActivity.java)
- [Fragment with menu](https://github.com/foens/appcompatsubmenu/blob/master/src/main/java/foo/bar/test/FragmentWithMenu.java)
- [Fragment without menu](https://github.com/foens/appcompatsubmenu/blob/master/src/main/java/foo/bar/test/FragmentWithoutMenu.java)
- [Menu xml](https://github.com/foens/appcompatsubmenu/blob/master/src/main/res/menu/test_menu.xml)
- [Activity layout](https://github.com/foens/appcompatsubmenu/blob/master/src/main/res/layout/login_activity.xml)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've the same problem. Even in some device the submenu can never show. I've made sure that the menu uses `myapp:` prefix instead of `android:` in the `res/menu`.

Answer (score 0):

Code has been removed, so I presume your problem has been resolved (and this question should be as well).

A shot in the dark though - the issue may be that you're missing setHasOptionsMenu.  Without it, the onCreateOptionsMenu is not reliably called when switching tabs, and your menu isn't populated.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```